# What sort of maths is this?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I have a number n

I increase n. I now have a new number n+1

I change my mind and decrease n: I now have a new number n-1

I change my mind again and increase. I am now back to n+1

No matter what I do along the above lines by increasing and decreasing, I can't get back to n.

What am I doing?

Clue

> The answer may be nearer than you think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it:

> The StackExchange vote system?
>  If you upvote someone, he goes from 0 to 1, but if you decide to downvote him afterwards, it'll get to -1, and we can never go back to 0.

Comment: I hope not, because you can in fact undo that. (Just click in the same place again.)

Comment: @ Gareth McCaughan - Yes but I clearly said, "No matter what I do *along the above lines*". That means by performing *the same set of operations*.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK sorry, I actually didn't think this would be the answer. It's too late to edit it but I can just delete it instead.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK without your clue i don't think that I could have find the answer so quickly ;)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Does increasing twice in a row count as performing the same set of operations to return to $n$?

Comment: @noedne - I meant no two the same in a row. Maybe I should have been clearer. You have obviously got the answer!